# R finding spatialpolygons within a spatialpolygon

Tags: r

I have a US House District polygon which is a simple outline of that house district. This is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.

```
CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

Next, I have a state's (Texas) Census block `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.

```
CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

My goal is to find the Census block groups that fit within that US House District.

My approach seems badly flawed.

```
mysp <- raster::aggregate(rbind(SUBBLOCK_ALL.shp, CD32.shp))
```

> Error in as(x, "SpatialPolygons") :    no method or default for
>   coercing “NULL” to “SpatialPolygons”

```
mysp <- rgeos::gIntersection(CD32.shp,SUBBLOCK_ALL.shp,byid = TRUE)
```

> Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td,
>   unaryUnion_if_byid_false,  :    trying to get slot "proj4string" from
>   an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots

```
mysp <- rgeos::gIntersection(CD32.shp,SUBBLOCK_ALL.shp,byid = TRUE)
```

> Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td,
>   unaryUnion_if_byid_false,  :    trying to get slot "proj4string" from
>   an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots

My question is what's a better possible approach?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: [stackoverflow.com/tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), *How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*: [stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and *How to Ask Good Questions* [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code that you've tried showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: And please format your questions...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using the `sf` package and the included `nc` dataset for North Carolina. This is obviously at a different scale than your problem but the premise should be the same. We can make a big square "district" covering some counties of North Carolina, and then use `filter` with `st_within` to keep only those that are within the boundary. You can use other predicates such as `st_intersects` depending on what you want to do with those that lie on the boundary. This is also generalisable to more districts, since `sf` geometry predicates actually compare all geometries in their two arguments.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, proj.4 4.9.3
nc <- system.file("shape", "nc.shp", package = "sf") %>%
  read_sf() %>%
  st_transform(3857)

district <- st_polygon(list(matrix(
  data = c(-9000000, 4000000, -8500000, 4000000, -8500000, 4500000, -9000000, 4500000, -9000000, 4000000),
  ncol = 2,
  byrow = TRUE
  ))) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 3857)

contained <- nc %>%
  filter(st_within(., district, sparse = FALSE))

plot(nc$geometry)
plot(district, add = TRUE)
plot(contained$geometry, add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-11 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).